# f(n)/log(n) = O(g(n)) ⇒ g(n) = Θ(f(n))?

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Is it possible to show, that `f(n)/log(n) = O(g(n)) => g(n) = Θ(f(n))`?

Right now I'm standing here:

1. `f(n)/log(n) = O(g(n))  ⇒  f(n)/log(n) ≤ c₁⋅g(n)  ⇒  f(n)/(c₁⋅log(n)) ≤ g(n)`
2. `g(n) = Θ(f(n))  ⇒  c₂⋅f(n) ≤ g(n) ≤ c₃⋅f(n)`

Then I say: `c₂ = 1/(c₁⋅log(n))  ⇒  c₂⋅f(n) ≤ g(n)`

If it is right, how do I show the upper bound?

Comment: As a hint, what if f(n) = n log n and g(n) = n?

Comment: Is this a code question??

Comment: @templatetypedef it goes without saying. But how do i show, that this expression applies to any two functions?

Comment: @bukko: Algorithmic complexity is typically allowed due to not having a better place to reside, since this has a lot more in common with development than pure mathematics.

Comment: The hint I'm giving you is that the property you're trying to prove isn't true, so there's no way to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't close to being true.  There are two problems.  First, the Theta relationship involves both upper and lower bounds, but (as you noticed) you only assume that g gives an upper bound on f.  So, for example, try f(n) = 0 and g(n) = n: the assumption is true but the conclusion is false.  Second, the factor of log(n) is not a constant factor, which will also prevent you from making a tight connection between f and g; for an example, see the comment from @templatetypedef.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you can disproof the assumption with an (generic) example:

Let `f(n) = g(n) ⋅ log(n)`, then  `f(n)/log(n) ∈ O(g(n))` holds, but obviously `g(n) ∉ Θ(f(n))`.

What you can show is this:

```
f(n)/h(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))   ⇒   g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)/h(n))   ⇒   g(n) ∈ O(f(n))
```